# How to call NOT NULL on GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

Here's an example query:

```
SELECT u.user_id, 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(photo_id) 
        FROM photos p WHERE p.user_id = u.user_id) 
    AS photo_ids FROM users u;
```

Now, lets say for example purposes we have these tables:

**Users:**

```
+---------+-----------------------+
| user_id |         email         |
+---------+-----------------------+
|       1 | webmaster@example.com |
|       2 | admin@example.com     |
+---------+-----------------------+
```

**Photos:**

```
+---------+----------+
| user_id | photo_id |
+---------+----------+
|       1 |        1 |
|       1 |        2 |
+---------+----------+
```

The results of the query above would form these results:

```
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | photo_ids |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | 1,2       |
|       2 | NULL      |
+---------+-----------+
```

How can I make it so that if the photo_ids column is NULL that it isn't returned?

I've tried:

```
SELECT u.user_id, 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(photo_id) 
        FROM photos p WHERE p.user_id = u.user_id) 
    AS photo_ids FROM users u
WHERE photo_ids IS NOT NULL;
```

but this returns a syntax error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'photo_ids' in 'where clause'
```

I've also tried `HAVING` as I've read it works with group_concat fields.

```
SELECT u.user_id, 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(photo_id) 
        FROM photos p WHERE p.user_id = u.user_id) 
    AS photo_ids FROM users u
HAVING photo_ids IS NOT NULL;
```

**RESULT:** 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING photo_ids IS NOT NULL' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use derived table in mysql and filter out to select only NOT NULL rows.

```
select * from
(
SELECT u.user_id, 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(photo_id) 
        FROM photos p WHERE p.user_id = u.user_id)  
    AS photo_ids FROM users u
) as DT
where DT.photo_ids not null;
```

> [Live Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4238d/5)

Answer (score 0):

Try this MySQL query :-

```
SELECT u.user_id, 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(photo_id) 
        FROM photos p WHERE p.user_id = u.user_id) 
    AS photo_ids FROM users u
WHERE photo_ids IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'photo_ids' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

Try `right join` :-

```
select Users.user_id,GROUP_CONCAT(photo_id) as photo_ids 
from Users right join Photos 
on Users.user_id=Photos.user_id group by Users.user_id
```

[Run query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5318/1)

Comment: Please see edit, #1054 - Unknown column 'photo_ids' in 'where clause'

Comment: Your edit throws the error `invalid use of group function`.

Comment: plz try this mysql query @Hobbyist